# Is the intersection of a component and the boundary of a closed set non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff, compact, connected space. Suppose that $A$ is a closed non-empty subset of $X$ such that $A\neq X$. Then how do we show that if $C$ is a connected component of $A$ the following is true: $C∩∂A≠∅$

I've tried to proceed by contradiction: if $C∩∂A=∅$, then I wanted to find a separation of $C$ to contradict that $C$ is connected, but I couldn't finish my idea.

I found the next proof, but I got lost in the last step:

Let $U=int(A)∩C$ and $V=int(A^c)∩C$. Both $U$ and $V$ are open in $C$ and $U∩V=∅$. Now $U∪V≠C$ because $C$ is connected. Finally, $∂A∩C=C∖(U∪V)$.

How is the last equation true?

Comment: That "next proof" requires A to have a not empty interior.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: But actually that's not a problem, because if A has empty interior the problem is solved trivially. The real problem with that "proof" is the definition of V, which turns to be empty.